# how to retrieve formula field value from crystal report 8.0

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6

How can I retrieve formula field value from `Crystal Report` 8.0 to a `vb6 variable`??

I used this one but it returns empty value.

```
varValue = crxReport.FormulaFields.GetItemByName("FieldName").Value
```

Comment: Whats the exact type of the object you're retrieving there?

Comment: Try replacing `Value` with `Text`.

Comment: replacing `Value` with `Text` only returns the formula, itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in VB6, just setup a Watch on `crxReport.FormulaFields.GetItemByName("FieldName")` and stop the code on that line.

You'll see the object and if it's properly referenced you can look at the properties and their values

Comment: It always show `varValue = ""` but if i used `crxReport.FormulaFields.GetItemByName("FieldName").Text` it returns the formula.

Comment: well that does make sense becaus eyou haven't assigned anyhting yet. The point of stopping there is to add a watch on `crxReport.FormulaFields.GetItemByName("FieldName")` then when it stops open the + to expand and look at it - is `FieldName` the actual name of the report field?

Comment: okay. I already viewed the report in CRViewer. The report retrieved values from the database and was calculated through the formula.

Answer (score 0):

1) The formula you used must be in Report Section otherwise it will not get executed and won't give any value.
2)Then after write this

```
crxReport.FormulaFields.GetItemByName("FieldName").Value
```

You Will Get Your Answer.